# Using SCOPE_IDENTITY multiple times for multiple tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is this okay to use SCOPE_IDENTITY() multiple times within one store procedure? Is there any chance of getting wrong SCOPE_IDENTITY value?

In the sp, there are three different insert statements for three different tables, table A SCOPE_IDENTITY value is passed into table B and table B SCOPE_IDENTITY value is passed into table C.

I am saving SCOPE_IDENTITY value into variable first

```
SET @EmpID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

and then passing @EmpID into insert statement.

Is there any risk of using SCOPE_IDENTITY() multiple times?

Also, i think SCOPE_IDENTITY is the best option for me as;

•IDENT_CURRENT returns the last identity value generated for a specific table in any session and any scope.

•@@IDENTITY returns the last identity value generated for any table in the current session, across all scopes.

•SCOPE_IDENTITY returns the last identity value generated for any table in the current session and the current scope.

Comment: You are doing it in the right way by saving the value into a variable. There is no harm in using SCOPE_IDENTITY any number of times.

Answer (score 0):

Reading up on msdn. I think that `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is the best option for you. The SCOPE_IDENTITY will always return the last inserted id in the target scope. The @@IDENTITY is not a good option because it can return ids from related triggers. Read more here:

> SCOPE_IDENTITY, IDENT_CURRENT, and @@IDENTITY are similar functions
>   because they return values that are inserted into identity columns.
>   IDENT_CURRENT is not limited by scope and session; it is limited to a
>   specified table. IDENT_CURRENT returns the value generated for a
>   specific table in any session and any scope. For more information, see
>   IDENT_CURRENT (Transact-SQL). SCOPE_IDENTITY and @@IDENTITY return the
>   last identity values that are generated in any table in the current
>   session. However, SCOPE_IDENTITY returns values inserted only within
>   the current scope; @@IDENTITY is not limited to a specific scope. For
>   example, there are two tables, T1 and T2, and an INSERT trigger is
>   defined on T1. When a row is inserted to T1, the trigger fires and
>   inserts a row in T2. This scenario illustrates two scopes: the insert
>   on T1, and the insert on T2 by the trigger. Assuming that both T1 and
>   T2 have identity columns, @@IDENTITY and SCOPE_IDENTITY will return
>   different values at the end of an INSERT statement on T1. @@IDENTITY
>   will return the last identity column value inserted across any scope
>   in the current session. This is the value inserted in T2.
>   SCOPE_IDENTITY() will return the IDENTITY value inserted in T1. This
>   was the last insert that occurred in the same scope. The
>   SCOPE_IDENTITY() function will return the null value if the function
>   is invoked before any INSERT statements into an identity column occur
>   in the scope. Failed statements and transactions can change the
>   current identity for a table and create gaps in the identity column
>   values. The identity value is never rolled back even though the
>   transaction that tried to insert the value into the table is not
>   committed. For example, if an INSERT statement fails because of an
>   IGNORE_DUP_KEY violation, the current identity value for the table is
>   still incremented.

Reference:

- [SCOPE_IDENTITY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)